# Query the first 15 users who added the most points using Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I Have a table `users` with a integer column called `points`. How can I query the first 15 `users` who added the most points?

Comment: Hmm, you must have some ideas at least as to how to solve this, have you tried some of them and if so what didn't work as expected?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a `User` model for `users` table, you can run this query to sort by `points` column

```
User.order('points DESC').limit(15)
```

This will return top 15 users having max number of points.